# NGINX deny IP wildcard?

Tags: nginx, ip, deny

I currently deny IP addresses like this in the nginx.conf file:

deny 42.22.11.531;

But how would I deny

deny 42.22.*.*;    <---- this obviously doesnt work, what is the correct syntax for nginx?

Ive seen:

deny 42.22.11.0/24 <---- not sure what this means, but it made me try

deny 42.22.0/999.0/999 <---- which fails.

So whats the correct syntax?

Answer (score 14):

This isn't nginx specific, it's a lack of understanding subnets in network math; /24 is a class C and /16 is a class B.

```
42.22.*.* = 42.22.0.0/16 = 42.22.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

Bookmark: http://www.subnet-calculator.com

Comment: Arrrhhh!! Classful networking! It burns!.

Comment: You're right though.  He wants to block a whole /16 network.  Ouch.  This is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: looks like he wants to block a whole bunch of Australia; 42.0.0.0 - 42.255.255.255 is all down under on the big island.

Comment: Nope... the IP I used is made up for the example

Answer (score 2):

deny 42.22.11.0/16 is the correct syntax.

More information on [nginx blocking](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/)

/16 signifies [Subnetwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). For further information click on the link to read.

Comment: Thats not enough though. I want the equivalent of:  42.22.0/24.0/24 but that fails

Comment: this comment doesn't address his question and you gave him the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next calc if you want:

https://industrysurfer.com/recursos/calculadoras/calculadora-ip-mascara/